# Unwanted stretching of nine-patch image for splash screen

Tags: android, nine-patch

I want to use a nine-patch image to make a splash screen for my application, which should look the same (square) in both portrait and landscape orientation.

My code is simple:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
  // more code here...
}
```

My resource file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Nine-patch image looks fine in Draw 9-patch utility:
[image]

But as the result the image is stretched: 
[image]

What's wrong? Can nine-patch images be used this way at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Can nine-patch image be used this way at all?` Well, no. Not properly.

Because 9 patches are meant to be **stretchable**.
A nice tutorial: https://radleymarx.com/2011/simple-guide-to-9-patch

You'd better use a square image and use it as a `source` (`android:src`), not as a background (`android:background`) for your ImageView.
Then you can ajust it by setting the `android:scaleType` attribute (`FIT_XY` ?).

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I accept the answer "nine-patch image can't be used this way".