# Square splash screen that look the same in both portrait and landscape device orientations

Tags: android

I want to use a nine-patch image to make a splash screen for my application, which should look the same (square) in both portrait and landscape orientation.

I tried to use a nine-path image for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752555/unwanted-stretching-of-nine-patch-image-for-splash-screen), but was answered that nine-patch images are not designed for this.

The code is simple:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
  // more code here...
}
```

I'm looking for a resoure solution which won't stretch my square image on the full screen. *ImageView* with *CENTER_INSIDE* scale type looks like what I need (according to the reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), but still no luck, the image is stretched.

My current resource file is:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/launch_image"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" >
</ImageView>
```

I'll appreciate and give a try to any idea!

Update: My layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/splashscreen" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_launch"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you set width and height  for ImageView?

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Can you provide more information about the layout you are using for your splash screen?

Comment: @Amsheer: Do you mean doing that in code when setting content view?

Comment: @krunalshah: I tried that, the result is the same

Comment: I mean set width height in xml.

Comment: @Amsheer: We need the picture to fit min(width, height) of the device, and we don't know its exact value.

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov: I've updated the question with the layout code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the following resource file makes square image look the same in both vertical and horizontal layout.
Thanks everyone for comments!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/launch_image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

create an xml bitamp and use it as background for the view. 
To prevent stretching you can specify android:gravity attribute.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/myimg"
        android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="top" >
    </bitmap>
```

Comment: The result is the same (image is stretched)

Answer (score 0):

By default new android project have basic folders for portrait orientation .Create a folder layout-land and drawable-land for landscape screen.Put your layout xml file in layout-land and required image for that screen in drawable-land.

Comment: I'd like to use the same square image for both portrail and landscape orientations. Anyway, I don't know device aspect, so even the vertical or horizontal image may be deformated.